# Publish tweets in drupal 7 site in real time

Tags: 7, social-network

I need to publish tweets from twitter in my Drupal 7 site. I use [twitter](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter) module but I need to publish this tweet in real time that's not the case with this module. Any one have an idea to fix this issue ??

Comment: all you need create rules for sending to twitter account

Answer (score 1):

Try [Selective Tweets](https://www.drupal.org/project/selective_tweets). As written in comparison to another Twitter module (Tweed Feed), Selective Tweets renders Tweets almost realtime:

> Tweet Feed does periodic imports of Tweets and turns them into nodes,
> while *Selective Tweets* renders Tweets almost **realtime** and saves none
> of them in the database as content. This is also the main difference,
> with the effect that Tweet Feed has a significant delay on the
> **realtime** Tweets. On the other hand, the Tweet Feed created nodes can
> be displayed in Views which gives big flexibility in the way of
> displaying Tweets.
>
> Use *Selective Tweets* when you want a light weight
> manner of displaying Tweets without database storing and you want no
> major delay in displaying **realtime** tweets.

Comment: thanks for help, i will try this, (i can't give you somes point because i havn't enough ponits :)  )

Comment: It's Selective Tweets you have to give a chance. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at https://www.drupal.org/project/activitystream yet? This module will create each tweet as a node so that you could further customize a view to display them in any manner you wish. By looking at the module page, the hashtags for Twitter posts seem to carry over and display naturally, so I don't think you will run into the issues that I ran into with the Feeds module. The Feeds/Feeds Importer module didn't seem to understand specific characters, so I'm curious as to if this Activity Stream would solve your issue and also be able to interpret hashtags as well.

Let me know if it worked out well or if it didn't work at all. I'm curious about this myself and may install it on a local server/test and post back later on.

Note, it seems like Twitter may have changed their API recently since this module came out. There is an updated version of it by the community just for Twitter @ https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/denison/2269357

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [twitter](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter) module which post to their own twitter account or a site-wide twitter account whenever they create new content or based on drupal actions or rules